# How did people think of the universe before Hubble?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, history

Did they think the universe had always existed? And was there even any serious scientific inquiry into the question, or was it pure speculation?

Comment: Might this be better suited for [History of Science](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)? In any event, the time before Hubble accounts for most of human history, and in fact most of scientific history, so this will need a long answer indeed.

Comment: So many different historic civilizations have comments on this, from the civilizations for example under an Abrahamic God and so on.

Comment: While this is clearly off-topic, statistically most "people" never thought about the question and they are still not thinking about it, so the phase transition between cosmologically naive and cosmologically educated humanity simply hasn't happened, yet, and that is completely independent of how you define "standard cosmology" of the local cultures.

Comment: To whomever voted to close this as *primarily opinion-based*: A question about the opinions of past generations may be "based on their opinions", but it *has* possible factual answers (derived from records of that time) and is not "primarily opinion-based" as a question. I do, however, think that this is not a *physics* question, and should be migrated to [hsm.SE].